# Get Latitude and Longitude values of placemark - Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I am using Google Earth API and I am new to it. I have marked a placemark using kml and added a click event to this. I want to get latitude and longitude values of this placemark. Though I am using **getLatitude()** and  **getLongitude()** function, but values are not accurate. I want exactly the same values as defined in kml. The values I get differ by points.

Is there any way to to this?

Thanks

Shubhra

Comment: show some of the code you are using, both javascript and kml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following sample for you. It fetches a kml file and attaches a click event to the placemark. Alerted latitude and longitude values are exactly the same as kml file. Hope it helps.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>sample.html</title>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAwbkbZLyhsmTCWXbTcjbgbRSzHs7K5SvaUdm8ua-Xxy_-2dYwMxQMhnagaawTo7L1FE1-amhuQxIlXw"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ge;
  google.load('earth', '1');

  function init() {
     google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
  }

  function initCB(instance) {
     ge = instance;
     ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

     var href = 'http://code.google.com/'
                + 'apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example.kml';

     google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {
           if (kmlObject)
           {
              ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
              google.earth.addEventListener(kmlObject, 'click', function(event) {
                var placemark = event.getTarget();
                alert('Latitude :' + placemark.getGeometry().getLatitude()
                     +' Longitude :' + placemark.getGeometry().getLongitude());
              });
           }
           if (kmlObject.getAbstractView() !== null)
              ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
     });                 
  }

  function failureCB(errorCode) {
  }   
  google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map3d" style="border: 1px solid silver; height: 400px; width: 600px;">  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked for me, but still there is some issue. Sometimes it give value that is not exactly the same. For example: if in kml longitude is 27.19737 , the placemark.getGeometry().getLongitude() returns 27.1973799999999995. Though the value is same after rounding but still not accurate and this is for some cases not all.